# Position of function in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a tutorial for react. I came across the below code

```
 const square = React.createElement('div', {
  style: {
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    margin: '10px',
  }
})

const container = React.createElement(
  // The first argument specifies the element's type
  'div',

  // The second argument specifies the element's attributes, or "props"
  { style: { border: '5px solid blue' } },

  // The remaining arguments list the element's children
  square,
  square
)

ReactDOM.render(container, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I understood that react dom will get the app element and render the 'container' element within. Inturn the container element calls the square element and everything works fine. when i try to add another element to sqaure element it is not rendering. the code is as follows

```
const square = React.createElement('div', {
  style: {
    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    margin: '10px',
  }
}, smallsquare)

const smallsquare = React.createElement('div', {
  style: {
    width: '50px',
    height: '50px',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    margin: '10px',
  }
})
```

Plunkr : [Plunkr template](https://plnkr.co/edit/XEEmMkOoXZpAdmI0u4xq?p=preview)

Note:I tried again by replacing the position of functions and its working

Kindly help me understand what i am missing

Comment: Its working for me when i put smallsquare to the top of the file

Comment: yeah i too tried it, but if its a javascript internally what is with the placing  functions in different positions. I did not find any mentions about positioning functions in react document. Could you please refer if you come across any

Comment: Because `smallSquare` has not been defined yet when you add it to the `square`'s `React.createElement()` method.

Comment: Traditionally if i have a javascript function at bottom of the page and call the function at head of the html immediately , then it may throw error as the function does not exist. In the above react case we have both the functions before the call of the main functions.  so does the flow is different in react?